# Delete all values in a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I can't seem to figure out how to delete all elements from a list in a dictionary key.

```
self.pieces = {
        'P1': [1, 0],
        'P2': [[1, 0], [0, 1]],
        'P3': [1, 0],
        'P4': [1, 0],
        'P5': [1, 0],
        'P6': [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]],
        'P7': [1, 0],
        'P8': [1, 0],
        'R1': [1, 0],
        'N1': [1, 0],
        'B1': [[1, 0], [1, 0]],
        'Q': [1, 0],
        'K': [1, 0],
        'B2': [1, 0],
        'N2': [1, 0],
        'R2': [1, 0],
    }
```

I have tried:

```
for i in self.pieces:
   filter(lambda a: a == '[]', self.pieces[i])
```

also:

```
  for i in self.pieces:
      for j in i:
           del self.pieces[i][0]
```

and various other random things which didn't work out. I need it to still have all the keys and '[ ]' as value without the elements inside

Comment: `for k in self.pieces: self.pieces[k] = []`?

Comment: @coldspeed I feel so stupid... the first comment is the solution. sorry for the waste of time :/.

Comment: So what should `self.pieces` look like after a successful modification?

Comment: @chepner `dict = {'P1': [ ],'P2': [ ] }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply reassign all the values to a empty list

```
pieces = {k : [] for k in pieces}
```

Or

```
for k in pieces:
    pieces[k].clear()
```

Comment: I would not recreate the entire thing when only the values need resetting. `for k in self.pieces: self.pieces[k].clear()` would also work.

Comment: @coldspeed added that as you commented :)

Comment: Just pointing out that these are actually different, should any other code hold references to the values.

Comment: @wim feel free to add edit in commentary, you have a little more scope of knowledge than I

Comment: @wim I do actually have code which uses the values. Is that what you mean with referencing? If so, would this cause problems?

Answer (score 3):

without rebuilding a new dictionary, loop on the values and apply `list.clear` on them since you know they're lists:

```
for v in pieces.values():
    v.clear()
```

Also *avoid* the fake-good idea of using `pieces = dict.fromkeys(pieces,[])` since lists are mutable and you'll end up with the same list for all keys (classic banging head error). This would have worked for immutable values like integers or strings, though, but not lists.

Answer (score -2):

I guess a good solution could be:

```
pieces = {
        'P1': [1, 0],
        'P2': [[1, 0], [0, 1]],
        'P3': [1, 0],
        'P4': [1, 0],
        'P5': [1, 0],
        'P6': [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]],
        'P7': [1, 0],
        'P8': [1, 0],
        'R1': [1, 0],
        'N1': [1, 0],
        'B1': [[1, 0], [1, 0]],
        'Q': [1, 0],
        'K': [1, 0],
        'B2': [1, 0],
        'N2': [1, 0],
        'R2': [1, 0],
    }

for p in pieces: 
  pieces[p] = []

print(pieces)
```

the output is

```
{'P1': [], 'P2': [], 'P3': [], 'P4': [], 'P5': [], 'P6': [], 'P7': [], 'P8': [], 'R1': [], 'N1': [], 'B1': [], 'Q': [], 'K': [], 'B2': [], 'N2': [], 'R2': []}
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just get the keys into a new list, delete the old dict and create a new dictionary with default values **[ ]** as follows

```
key_list = [ i for i in pieces.keys() ] # Get the keys into a new list
del pieces                              # Delete the dictionary
pieces=dict.fromkeys(key_list, [])      # Create a new dict from key_list and default value []
```

Comment: big no-no (see the last comment on my answer) "avoid the fake-good idea of using pieces = dict.fromkeys(pieces,[]) since lists are mutable and you'll end up with the same list for all keys"

Comment: Agreed. My bad. Could have used `.clear()`. Thanks for pointing out.